# Oracle - select records in which a subset does not repeat

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle data set with the following columns F1, F2, F3, F4 as follows:

```
A, B, C, D
A, B, C, E
A, F, C, D
A, G, C, D
```

I would like to filter out the duplicate fields in column F1 and F2 only. From the example above, I see line 1 and 2 have identical values (A,B) in Field (F1,F2), I need to get either

```
A, B, C, D
or
A, B, C, E
```

but not both. So the final result I expect would be:

```
A, B, C, D
A, F, C, D
A, G, C, D
```

or

```
A, B, C, E
A, F, C, D
A, G, C, D
```

How do I issue an Oracle statement to achieve my goal?
I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (ROWID,F1,F2) IN
(SELECT DISTINCT  ROWID, F1,F2 FROM T)
```

but the statement does not help and still print everything out.
Please help.

Below is the quick and dirty script to create the testing data set:

```
  CREATE TABLE "T" 
   (    
    "F1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "F2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "F3" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "F4" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) 

Insert into T (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('A','B','C','D');
Insert into T (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('A','B','C','E');
Insert into T (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('A','F','C','D');
Insert into T (F1,F2,F3,F4) values ('A','G','C','H');
```

Comment: The rules are still not enough. Please explain via test case. How would `SQL` return you two results on basis of your `OR` logic?

Comment: Thank you Lalit for looking into my question. I only need 1 set of result either or. Do not need both. Either A, B, C, D
A, F, C, D
A,G,C,D                                                             or                                                                A, B, C, E
A, F, C, D
A, G, C, D

Comment: I just see that you need either 1st or 2nd row to be eliminated. i.e. either D or E for the fourth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like that corresponding to your needs:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T 
JOIN (SELECT F1, F2, MIN(ROWID) RID FROM T GROUP BY(F1,F2)) O
ON T.ROWID = O.RID
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcf9c/4

The inner query will remove duplicated on `F1,F2` (*deterministically* keeping the *minimum* `ROWID` in case of duplicates). Then the outer select is a simple join on ROWID to extract the entire row.

---

If T is a *view*, you cannot use `ROWID`. So you will have to rely on something like that instead:

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3, MIN(F4) F4
FROM T 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT F1, F2, MIN(F3) F3 FROM T GROUP BY(F1,F2)) O
GROUP BY(F1,F2,F3);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcf9c/8

The key idea here is to create a 3-uple with distinct `F1,F2` and the corresponding minimum `F3` (inner query). Then extending that 3-uple by adding the minimum `F4` (outer query). It can easily be generalized to N-uple by nesting more queries.

Comment: to extend my question a bit, will your solution be the same if my table T is actually a view? Then RowID will not be applicable?

Comment: @user1205746 You don't have any practical way to _identify_ a row from a view. So you must rely on totally different solution. As there is no other answer, maybe it doesn't worth asking an other question. Just edit you question and un-accept my answer?

Comment: I am just asking out of curiosity and see if it could be extended. Your answer still stay and is still valid as this is what I need. I appreciate your response. With the view, I guess I will use the rowId of the underlying table where the view is based on, then join back to the view.

Comment: @user1205746 I've edited my answer to provide an alternative option. Could you check if it works as expected?

Comment: If it is a view, then there should be a table where the view was based on, could it the min(rowID) on that table be used and then join back as you did? F3 is a totally independent field and using F3 would not provide the expected result.

Comment: @user1205746 Have you tried it? I don't group by `F3`, but by `MIN(F3)` for a given pair `F1,F2`. I've just aliased the column (`MIN(F3)` is called `F3`) to be able to use a `NATURAL JOIN`. If it doesn't work for your actual data, could you update the sqlfiddle with some problematic rows, and provide the link?

Comment: I will try it out after I finish my current project and let you know. Currently your provided solution is good enough for me. The extra question was just my pure curiosity in case for someone else who comes across the same scenario but has a view instead of a table

Answer (score 0):

Use this for better performance (since it avoids joins)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
F1, 
F2, 
LAST_VALUE(F3) OVER (PARTITION BY F1, F2) AS F3, 
LAST_VALUE(F4) OVER (PARTITION BY F1, F2) AS F4
FROM T
```